# RxSwift multiple observable in map

Tags: rx-swift, reactivex

I ran into a situation where I would fetch an API which will generate json data of registered users. I would then have to loop through each user and fetch their avatar from remote url and save it to disk. I can perform this second task inside `subscribe` but this is not a best practice. I am trying to implement it with `map`, `flatMap` etc.

Here is my sample code:

```
self.dataManager.getUsers()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribeOn(globalScheduler)
            .map{ [unowned self] (data) -> Users in
                var users = data
// other code for manipulating users goes here
// then below I am trying to use another loop to fetch their avatars

                if let cats = users.categories {
                    for cat in cats  {
                        if let profiles = cat.profiles {
                            for profile in profiles {
                                if let thumbnail = profile.thumbnail,
                                    let url = URL(string: thumbnail) {
                                    URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: URLRequest(url: url))
                                        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                                        .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                                            // Update Image
                                            if let img = UIImage(data: response.data) {
                                                try? Disk.save(img, to: .caches, as: url.lastPathComponent)
                                            }
                                        }, onError: { (error) in

                                        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return users
            }
            .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] (users) in

            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

There are 2 problems in this code. First is with the `rx` on `URLSession` which execute the task in background on another thread and there is no way to acknowledge the main `subscribe` back when this operation will finish. Second is with the loop and rx which is not efficient as it should generate multiple observables and then process it.

Any idea to improve this logic is welcome.

Comment: I would like to recommend `af_image` library to set the avatars and get rid of nested subscribers. Do you tried that?

Comment: That library will download the image async and I couldn't found a way to notify main `subscribe`

Comment: It accepts a completion though, if I were you I would make some of the main subscribe variables in `class` scope and use af_image. Otherwise you should deal with nested subscription. I do not think there would be a 3rd way. If someone could propose another way I am interested too. So lets wait! Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a fun puzzle.

The "special sauce" that solves the problem is in this line:

```
.flatMap { 
    Observable.combineLatest($0.map { 
        Observable.combineLatest(
            Observable.just($0.0), 
            URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: $0.1)
                .materialize()
        ) 
    }) 
}
```

The `map` before the line creates an `Observable<[(URL, URLRequest)]>` and the line in question converts it to an `Observable<[(URL, Event<Data>)]>`.

The line does this by:

1. Set up the network call to create an `Observable<Data>`
2. Materialize it to create an `Observable<Event<Data>>` (this is done so an error in one download won't shutdown the entire stream.)
3. Lift the URL back into an Observable which gives us an `Observable<URL>`
4. Combine the observables from steps 2 & 3 to produce an `Observable<(URL, Event<Data>)>`.
5. Map each array element to produce `[Observable<(URL, Event<Data>)>]`
6. Combine the observables in that array to finally produce `Observable<[(URL, Event<Data>)]>`

Here is the code

```
// manipulatedUsers is for the code you commented out.
// users: Observable<Users>
let users = self.dataManager.getUsers()
    .map(manipulatedUsers) // manipulatedUsers(_ users: Users) -> Users
    .asObservable()
    .share(replay: 1)

// this chain is for handling the users object. You left it blank in your code so I did too.
users
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { users in

    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// This navigates through the users structure and downloads the images.
// images: Observable<(URL, Event<Data>)>
let images = users.map { $0.categories ?? [] }
    .map { $0.flatMap { $0.profiles ?? [] } }
    .map { $0.compactMap { $0.thumbnail } }
    .map { $0.compactMap { URL(string: $0) } }
    .map { $0.map { ($0, URLRequest(url: $0)) } }
    .flatMap { 
        Observable.combineLatest($0.map { 
            Observable.combineLatest(
                Observable.just($0.0), 
                URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: $0.1)
                    .materialize()
            ) 
        }) 
    }
    .flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
    .share(replay: 1)

// this chain filters out the errors and saves the successful downloads.
images
    .filter { $0.1.element != nil }
    .map { ($0.0, $0.1.element!) }
    .map { ($0.0, UIImage(data: $0.1)!) }
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .bind(onNext: { url, image in
        try? Disk.save(image, to: .caches, as: url.lastPathComponent)
        return // need two lines here because this needs to return Void, not Void?
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// this chain handles the download errors if you want to.
images
    .filter { $0.1.error != nil }
    .bind(onNext: { url, error in
        print("failed to download \(url) because of \(error)")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. Just asking if there is any efficient way to combine both users and images observables and return result from user and only error from images to users observable only?

Comment: Do you mean you want an `Observable<(Users, [UIImage])>`? That doesn't sound too useful but it can be done. I think a more useful output would be `Observable<[(Profile, UIImage)]>` which can also be done. However, you need to focus more on the outputs you want. What is the output you are trying to achieve? Is this to fill a table view cell (in which case each cell should do its own image download) or something else? For these more vague questions, the RxSwift slack might be a better place.

Comment: yes the output is to fill tableview cells. For this output only Users result is required and only interested to know if error for Image download happened, so the result for user can be skipped. Otherwise your solution is enough. : )

Comment: may be you can share this alternate solution on slack or in direct message.

Comment: I can't share a solution when I don't know the problem. Hit me up on the RxSwift slack and we can talk.